# FindAndModify Atomic Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

i have read about FIndAndModify:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/findAndModify+Command:
**this command can be used to atomically modify a document (at most one) and return it.**

This means that the locking is at level of Document, Collections, Database?

I think Document, but in other post I have read Database.

da.

Answer (score 0):

Read/write locks in mongodb right now global (database). But there is [feature in jira](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0/) about lock per collection. So i hope per collection locking will be done in mongodb soon..

**Update:**
With MongoDB 3.2.2 using WiredTiger Storage implementation as default engine, MongoDB use default locking at document level.It was introduced in version 3.0 but made default in version 3.2.2. Therefore MongoDB now has document level locking 
[read/write lock](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2/)

Comment: I'm sorry but i read that actually ATOMIC operation in MongoDB is for "Document": are you sure of that?

As you write, if a use FindAndModify on collection "User" than I'll lock query for collection "Friends": right?

Comment: @Dada: yes, atomic operations only for one document, but write lock in mongodb still global(see update).. With atomic update almost impossibly rewrite someone changes, because of you not loading document to update it.

Comment: So, collection.Update not lock entire Database. Collection.FindAndModify lock the database. Right?